# removing characters from a value in dictionary in python

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, python-2.7

Structure is as follows:

```
{"A": [{
            "A": "",
            "B": "2",
            "C": "3QWE",
            "D": 1800,
            "E": null,
            "F": null
        },
        {
            "A": "",
            "B": "2",
            "C": "XYT17",
            "D": 1800,
            "E": "3, 1*",
            "F": null
        },
        {
            "A": "",
            "B": "N8HTY",
            "C": "XYT17",
            "D": 1800,
            "E": "7,6,(5)**",
            "F": null
        },
        {
            "A": "",
            "B": "1AJ21",
            "C": "XYT17",
            "D": 1800,
            "E": "7,6,5",
            "F": null
        }
       ],
   "B": [{
            "A": "",
            "B": "LS231",
            "C": "XYT17",
            "D": 1800,
            "E": "1,2,3",
            "F": null
        },
        {
            "A": "",
            "B": "22GHE",
            "C": "XYT17",
            "D": 1800,
            "E": "3, 1*",
            "F": null
        }
      ]
}
```

I want the '*' and '(' and ')' to be removed from the value of the key 'E' if it is present
The output should be as follows for "E"

i.e. "E":"7,6,(5)**" --->  "E":"7,6,5"

```
  "E":"3, 1*" ---> "E":"3,1"



 "E":"1,2,3" stays the same
```

Also if after processing "1*" i have the final output as only one digit say "1" then how can i convert it to integer before updating the value.

What i did was

```
x=copy.copy(item['E']) 
for char in '*':              
  x = x.replace(char,'') 
item['E']=x
```

This gets me the result as a string.
Now if i want it to be stored as an integer value if there is only a single digit then what should be done?
 I tried

item['E'] = int(x)

to get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this structure a python dictionary or JSON?  I'm wondering about the 'null' values.

Comment: Its a python _dictionary_ dumped as _json_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will strip anything not a digit or comma from `E`:

```
import re
for a in data.values():
    for d in a:
        d['E'] = re.sub(r'[^\d,]', '', d['E'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your current structure is stored in a variable called `data`:

```
for arr in data.values():
    for item in arr:
        item['E'] = item['E'].replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('*', '')
```

This assumes the structure is consistent and `"E"` will always be a key in the dictionaries.

If this is a JSON string and not a Python dictionary, you will first need to parse the JSON:

```
import json
data = json.loads(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using

```
 x=copy.copy(item['E']) 
 for char in '()*':              
      x = x.replace(char,'') 


 z = len(x)
 if z == 1:
      item['E'] = int(x)
  else:
     item['E'] = x
```